# rename upper lower case filenames no more possible

Tags: xubuntu, filesystem, ext4

After today's major upgrade of Xubuntu, it have been downgraded to Windows, and will NOT distinguish between upper and lower case letters!!
On a laptop that haven't been upgraded it still works fine, and sees 'Name' and 'name' as 2 distinct filenames.
Why have it been Windowsified?

I shut down my labtop last night and have just rebooted - and Horray it works again Unix style, like we love and expect!
Yesterday a reboot did not fix that aberant behaviour!

Sorry for my panic attack, I was sorting my photos from both my phone and my camera.
I was using Thunars beloved bulk rename feature like I always do and getting a lot of rename failed name allready exist when trying to change certain letters to uppercase - like I would get from my girls Windows machine if I tried to do as I am used to on Nix systems.

What triggered that behaviour I do not know!

Comment: Where and how do you see that happening? In Thunar file manager? In which directories? Everywhere, in your home directory, or on a removable drive? If the latter, what is the file system of that drive?

Comment: If you want a more specific answer, include the results of `pwd ; df -hT .` for the directory you are using in your question.

Comment: What major upgrade to Xubuntu?  What version of Xubuntu are you running?  I use Xubuntu 20.04 and I have not seen any "major upgrades" recently to it.

Comment: What major upgrade to Xubuntu are you talking about?  What packages?  We currently don't even know your release, and most upgraded packages are to that Ubuntu base system you've not yet provided details of. We can't know what Xfce until we know release details also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unix, filename case sensitivity is largely a feature of the underlying filesystem.  If you have multiple mounted filesystems, it is possible that some are case sensitive and some are not.

For example, the vfat filesystem is not case sensitive.

To check what filesystem the current directory is using, run the command `df -hT .`  (note trailing dot)

With your added information in the question, my guess is that you accidentally tried to run the rename script not on the unix filesystem, but on the camera's disk (sd card?) which is very extremely likely to be in vfat format, which does not recognize case to distinguish names.

Comment: Exactly. Yesterday my ext4 file-system behaved like unix, after upgrade it acts obnoxiously like windows - it the new upgraded Xubuntu that have this faulty behaviour!

Comment: Please give output from the suggested commands.  You likely are confused about what actually caused this.

Comment: Confused and a bit scared IdoLoveNixWaysOfHandlingLetters.
Not all devices love blanks in filenames, so capitalicing first letter makes names more readable and secure it works on even old hardware!
Thanks for your quick responce,

Comment: I think it's not as bad as you might think.  Updated answer to reflect new info in your question.